# Microsoft Word: Does the heading style from a table appear in the table of contents/document map of a document?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

My question is simple:

I have a text. I apply the heading 1 style to it and the text appear in a table of contents/document map.

Lets say, that text I want to put it in heading row of a simple table in my document. Can I make it appear in a table of contents/document map anymore?

Comment: You can use Home Styles (Heading1 for example) in Table and it will appear in the table of contents

Comment: By 'document map', I assume you mean the Navigation pane that opens on the left side of the window when, for example, you press Ctrl+F. Are you using 'table of contents' to refer to the same thing, or do you mean an actual TOC that you insert from, e.g., the References tab? Table text that you style as a Heading 1 (or 2, 3, etc.) won't show up in the Navigation pane. However, it should show up in a TOC.

Comment: Yes the navigation in the left area. And I am talking about Reference Tab. That sucks if doesnt show. :(

Answer (score 0):

A heading 1 style in the repeating row of a table will appear in the table of contents but not in the document map. In fact, the heading 1 style won't appear if it's placed anywhere in the table. I cannot find a work around for that.

Comment: Yes, this what I was talking about. Sorry for the delayed answered. There is no o solution for this situation I see...

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve? The way MS Word functions is probably correct since it's not really possible to link to something if it's repeating on every page so the way I see it the way it works with the document map is correct and the TOC is just a bug. If you can explain what you are trying to do there may be an alternative instead.

Comment: See the picture: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzPYA0WJxujhUFBnWlh4Yk85bmM

Comment: Why do you need the heading in a repeating row is what I mean? Can you do it some other way instead?

Comment: @adam there are use cases for this.. i may have say 100 row x 5 column table. And each row, col 1 may have country names.. Argentina, Bolivia, Combodia to Zambia.. set as H1 or some headings.. and I should be able to jump to the country using navigation pane on the left.. with a single click.. jump form Combodia to Zambia and Back.. for example.. yes we all know we can move the country names outside the table to make it work and use the normal H1 style as usual.. that's not the point.. the point is currently word doesn't work for headings inside cell although it shows in toc (good not great!)

Comment: i hope somebody will have a work around where heading or something will work inside table cells.. so as to appear in navigation pane. I REPEAT.. the normal answer of moving Heading 1 outside the table is NOT the answer.. either it can be done or with some work around.. or it cannot be done..

Comment: @ihightower. I understand, it's odd Microsoft haven't fixed this yet. They have said many years ago they are looking into it but haven't moved much since. You can however track the "progress" here: https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9629649-headers-in-table-not-displayed-in-navigation-pane?page=2&per_page=20